# Accessing UIViewController programmatically in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm working on an app that has several ViewControllers and there is a particular ViewController "login ViewController" that i would like to be accessed from almost every UIViewController, i know i can achieve this by using segue from each controller to LoginViewController which i'm sure is not the best solution, what is the best solution for to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Use this...variable `vc` return the viewcontroller you are looking for

```
  UIStoryboard *aStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  YourViewController *vc = [aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController"];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can probably do something like this

```
static LoginViewController *instance; //place in the implementation

- (void) viewDidLoad {
     instance = self;
}

+(LoginViewController *) getInstance { //use this method to access the instance (declare in header)
    return instance;
}
```

then just import the header where you need to access it and you're done

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html

Instantiating a Storyboard’s View Controller Programmatically

Listing 2-2  Instantiating another view controller inside the same storyboard

```
- (IBAction)presentSpecialViewController:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    SpecialViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SpecialViewController"];

    // Configure the new view controller here.

    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should create a base view controller which will be subclassed by every controller that needs the login view controller.
Then in your base viewController you can create a method like this:

```
-(YourLoginViewController*)giveMeTheLoginController {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
    YourLoginViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourLoginViewControllerIdentifier"];
    return viewController;
}
```

If you don't want another base view controller you can use the same method in your view controllers to obtain a new instance of the view controller from storyboard.

Also using the segues from each view controller is a good way, the segues are used to define your navigation.